# Kivy Encoding Japanese (Unicode)

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, kivy

I'm trying to get Japanese characters in my app. From the documentation and other sources I found that Label(text=u'我是中文', font_name='fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF') should work (arialuni font should be able to handle Japanese/Chinese characters). However I'm wondering how do I specify this in the Kivy language in the .kv file? This is what I tried:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Design1(BoxLayout):
    pass


class KanjiLayoutApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Design1()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    KanjiLayoutApp().run()
```

kanjilayout.kv:

```
<Design1>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        font_name: 'data/fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF'
        text: u'速 dsf'
```

However this gives me "é€Y dsf". Also
text: '速 dsf' without u doesn't work.

p.s. adding あい (kana) to the text: text: '速 dsf　あい' gives even more errors: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 369: character maps to < undefined>

Comment: Full kana (hiragana) error:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\Apps\KanjiLayout\main.py", line 16, in <module>
     KanjiLayoutApp().run()
   File "D:\Apps\_Kivy-1.8.0-py3.3-win32\kivy\kivy\app.py", line 765, in run
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "D:\Apps\_Kivy-1.8.0-py3.3-win32\kivy\kivy\app.py", line 585, in load_kv

     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "D:\Apps\_Kivy-1.8.0-py3.3-win32\kivy\kivy\lang.py", line 1433, in load_file
     data = fd.read()
   File "D:\Apps\_Kivy-1.8.0-py3.3-win32\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line
 23, in decode

Comment: maybe try `text: u'\u9FXX dsf' or whatever the code point is rather than the literal character

Comment: return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 369: character maps to < undefined>

Comment: text: '\u4E5D' for example seems to work, thanks Joran Beasley, however in the kivy/examples/widgets/unicode_textinput.py it is able to convert a string of characters. However I'm a bit confused which part of the code gets this done. So I hoped for a clearer explanation.

Comment: you would need to define the encoding at the top of your kv file put the line `#encoding: utf-8` as the first line of your script  (at least i think thats the line, and it assumes you are using utf8 encoding)  (and Im not entirely sure that kivy supports the encoding directive)

Comment: Joran I just tried, but still the same problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your kv file is using utf-8 character encoding, and it should work fine. Most decent text editors will allow you to select the encoding.

Do not use `u''`, as the file is already unicode (attempting to use `u''` will result in decode errors).

I had issues with the arialuni font (didn't show kanji, but it did show the kana, and the top half was cut off of all characters, including Western letters). So I used a different font instead (TakaoPMincho - easy to install in Ubuntu).

kanjitest.kv:

```
<TestWidget>:
    Label:
        text: '速 dsf　あい'
        font_name: 'TakaoPMincho.ttf'
        font_size: sp(48)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So the problem was in how the file was saved.
I got it working in .py file with Builder.load_string, however converting .kv still gives problems:

 >>    1:ï»¿#:ã\u20ac\u20ackivy 1.8.0
       2:#: import utils kivy
       3:#: import os os
 ...
 Invalid data after declaration.

I try to figure this out after some sleep :p

Comment: Ok I did some more testing. I also got it working if I type txt = "速 dsf　あい" in the .py file and in the .kv file: text = root.txt. However changing the Encoding of the .kv file breaks it... How did you do it in the .kv file?

Comment: Try using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/); it will show you the current encoding of the file and allow you to change it (plus it's one of the best text editors for Windows). As long as the file is in UTF-8, it should work fine. If it doesn't, then this is a Windows-related bug which should be [reported to Kivy](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues) (since it works on Linux).

Comment: I tried it with Notepad, Notepad++ and PyCharm. All 3 the same problem and indeed I worked now with Windows and Python 3.3. I will try it with Linux and 2.7 soon.

Answer (score 2):

For windows users who want to have their other language in a .kv file you have to manually load a .kv file using `utf-8` encoding. Note that to avoid it being auto loaded and throwing a decoding exception anyways the .kv file must be named differently than your app. This is because windows assumes that a file is `cp1252` encoded unless told otherwise. You must also use a font that supports the characters you are trying to display. I'm using Meiryo for Japanese. So for example:

main.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder

#These two lines are what opens the .kv file and uses the rules written within.
with open("Japanese.kv", encoding='utf-8') as f: # Note the name of the .kv 
                                                 # doesn't match the name of the App
    Builder.load_string(f.read())

class JapaneseTest(Widget):
    pass

class JapaneseTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return JapaneseTest()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    JapaneseTestApp().run()
```

Japanese.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<JapaneseTest>:
    Label:
        size: self.texture_size
        font_size: 36
        font_name: "meiryo.ttc"
        text: "こんにちは!"
```

Of course make sure that the .kv file is written in the encoding that you specified. Most decent text editors should allow you to change this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Japanese chars, download the this [ttf](https://code.google.com/p/ms2ginger/downloads/detail?name=DroidSansJapanese.ttf):

Specify the full path to your `.ttf` file:

```
<Design1>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        font_name:"/path/to/DroidSansJapanese.ttf"
        text: '速'
```

I have not tested as an update today has screwed up something in kivy but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Baltic letters and manage to find solution:

use u'\u0100' - this for example will create Latvian letter "Ā", so you have to find unicode codes for all your chars. Don't ask me why it needs double unicode declaration, but for me if I use u'Ā' it would work on Android but make crap on win pc, but in case of '\u0100' I would have correct letter on win pc but crap on Android; when double escaped it works on both.
Hope this helps someone else too :) cause I wasted few hours before figure it out :)
PS. for Japanese you might need to use U'\U(8char hex)'